# How do I make the shell understand the wildcard character that is being passed through subprocess.call()

Tags: python

When I execute the script I get this error:

```
['grep', 'PORTALSHARED', '*']
grep: *: No such file or directory
```

The same command works just fine when I execute on the shell.

Below is the script:

```
a = shlex.split('grep PORTALSHARED *')
print a

for pdir, _, _ in os.walk(r'/Users/skandasa/perforce/projects/releases/portal-7651'):
   os.chdir(pdir)
   print os.getcwd()
   subprocess.call(a)
```

I have tried adding `shell = True` but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is expanded by the shell, so if you want `subprocess.call()` to work on that, you would need to pass in `shell=True` . Example -

```
a = 'grep PORTALSHARED *'
subprocess.call(a, shell=True)
```

Please do note, when using `shell=True` , you should send in the complete string as the command, not the `split` version.

---

But given that, I do not think you really need that the `os.chdir()`, you can rather try -

```
a = 'grep PORTALSHARED {}'
for pdir, _, _ in os.walk(r'/Users/skandasa/perforce/projects/releases/portal-7651'):
   subprocess.call(a.format(pdir + '/*'), shell=True)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending in complete string, not the split version as I have said in the answer.

Comment: I am sorry that comment was for the other answers. I think your solution seems to work as its taking some time to get the results. By the way could you please let me know how can I pass `grep PORTALSHARED * | awk -F '[' '{print $1}'` command through `subprocess` as `shlex.split` does only this  `['grep', 'PORTALSHARED', '*', '|', 'awk', '-F', '[', '{print $1}']` where subprocess needs each item to be in single quotes.

Comment: You cannot use `shlex.split()` with shell=True. so do not split , directly use the string, use `double quotes` to create the string, rather than single quotes . Like `"grep PORTALSHARED * | awk -F '[' '{print $1}'"`

Comment: Thats right but `*` falls in between the whole command I need to how to deal with that.

Comment: What do you mean fails inbetween the whole command? what is the failure?